# Bullet: btBvhTriangleMeshShape crash

Tags: c++, assertion, bullet

So I have this line of code:

```
new btBvhTriangleMeshShape(meshInterface, true);
```

Which crashes my program. Apparently, somewhere inside the function there is an `assert(numIndices>0)` line, which is causing the crash.

If I add one more `false` parameter on the end of my line so it looks like:

```
new btBvhTriangleMeshShape(meshInterface, true, false);
```

I tell it not to generate the bounding volume data, and it continues fine (no crash). So my question is: Why is it when I clearly have indices in `meshInterface`, it crashes and says I have no indices.

Additional Info:

`meshInterface` is created like this:

```
btTriangleMesh *meshInterface = new btTriangleMesh();
for(uint i = 0; i < terrainMesh.position.size(); i++) {
    //don't remove duplicate vertex because there won't ever be any
    meshInterface->findOrAddVertex(toBt(terrainMesh.position[i]), false);
}
for(uint i = 0; i < terrainMesh.index.size(); i++) {
    meshInterface->addIndex(terrainMesh.index[i]);
}
```

I already have my data set up in another object, and I just load it into the bullet setup.

And here you can see there is clearly valid data in my `meshInterface`. The mesh is a flat plane.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From btTriangleMesh.h:

```
// findOrAddVertex is an internal method, use addTriangle instead
int findOrAddVertex(const btVector3& vertex, bool removeDuplicateVertices);
```

So try using addTriangle instead.

EDIT: It is more efficient to use btTriangleIndexVertexArray instead of btTriangleMesh.

Comment: To my surprise, it actually works. However, it is unnecessary, and I would to find a way to make mine work instead of this as a workaround. I already have my data set up in the way bullet wants it, and with your technique, I convert it to a temporary format, and then bullet converts it BACK to the way I had it before. TLDR: yours works but is inefficient.

Comment: The comment on addTriangle says it's better to use btTriangleIndexVertexArray directly. It looks like the constructor for btTriangleIndexVertexArray would be more efficient, but you would have to add a constructor to btTriangleMesh that takes the proper arguments (maybe there's another way to do it though?). I've also had to modify btTriangleMesh in order to get triangles by index.

Comment: I'll try it, I rejected using a `btTriangleIndexVertexArray` for some reason in the past, but I can't remember it now. I think since it is still a subclass of `btStridingMeshInterface`, I won't need to use any special technique for the ctor. Thanks!

Comment: Oh nice. I assumed the btBvhTriangleMeshShape constructor took a btTriangleMesh*, but I see I was wrong.

Comment: Well, I've got it to run fine using `btTriangleIndexVertexArray`, but I'm pretty sure the data is screwed up bad. I'll figure it out. But seriously oh my god, why does bullet have to be so low level!? Can't they just use a vector, instead of raw pointers? Jesus.